# .htaccess custom ErrorDocument in upper folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, errordocument

Let's say I have this directory structure:

- .htaccess with [specification of ErrorDocuments]
- fo1

  - ed [folder with ErrorDocuments]

    - ed401.html
- fo2 [folder with public website]

  - .htaccess
  - .htpasswd

The main .htaccess contains

```
ErrorDocument 401 /www/htdocs/path/to/fo1/ed/ed401.html
```

The public accessible .htaccess contains

```
AuthUserFile /www/htdocs/path/to/fo2/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName 'Bitte Zugangsdaten eingeben'
AuthType Basic    
require valid-user
```

After canceling the auth-request of the server I get the following message:

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.
>
> Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

1. Why is there an additional 401 error
2. Why isn't my custom ErrorDocument displayed?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument , if it begins with a slash, it's relative from the document root.  Is that the correct path?

Comment: If I remove the beginning slash I just get the string (of the path) displayed:
www/htdocs/path/to/fo1/ed/ed401.html

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `/fo1/ed/ed401.html` ?  Assuming the top .htaccess is in the document root.

Comment: Same problem. The real document root should be htdocs I guess (I'm on a shared server so "path/to/" is my account name / directory.

/fo1/ed/ed401.html:
With slash at the beginning -> additional 401 error
Without slash at the beginning -> displayed string

Comment: What is full URL you enter in browser to access `fo1/ed/ed401.html`?

Comment: This folder is not accessible by a browser. It's outside of the websites root folder.